# Incremental array list with min & max numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to work through this problem from Codewars and for the life of me cannot figure out what's wrong.

***Given the a list of numbers, return the list so that the values increment by 1 for each index up to the maximum value.***

This is the solution that I've come up with, but it doesn't work for these data sets:  [6, 9] and [-1, 4].  Here's a link to the problem if you'd like to try it yourself:  [codewars - lario & muigi](http://www.codewars.com/kata/56b29582461215098d00000f/train/javascript)

```
function pipeFix(numbers) {
  var firstNum = numbers[0];
  var lastNum = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
  var iterations = (lastNum - firstNum) + 1;
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = firstNum; i <= iterations; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

If you can point me in the right direction I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are not incrementing by one from the minimum value up to the maximum value.

**This solution should work:**

```
function pipeFix(numbers) {
  var max = Math.max.apply(this, numbers);
  var min = Math.min.apply(this, numbers);
  var result = []
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    result.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution doesn't work is that a condition in `for` statement is incorrect.

For a set: [6, 9] you get `firstNum` = 6 and `lastNum` = 9. This part is ok. The problem is `iterations` variable, which in this case is 4.
In `for` statement you start from value 6, but the condition

`i <= iterations`

says that variable `i` must be less or equal 4. You break this condition in the first iteration, so the the array you get in return is empty.

Change `for` statement to:

```
for (var i = firstNum; i <= lastNum; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

In fact you don't need `iterations` variable any more.

Elvio Cavalcante's solution will work too, even if you swap the numbers in input array and you get [9, 6] instead of [6, 9].

Comment: Thanks Marcin!  The answer was right in front of me!